# Reliable method to convert national currency to bitcoin

Tags: exchanges, currencies

I'm relatively new to Bitcoin and cryptocurrency so please excuse my newbie question.

I'm looking for a reliable method to convert national currency (i.e. "normal" money) into Bitcoin. A quick google turns up a plethora of exchanges, but I have no idea how to judge which are reliable.  By "reliable", I have two chief concerns:

1. That my information will be treated securely and privately; and
2. That the funds I deposit will arrive in my Bitcoin wallet.

Please give me some advice on an exchange or exchanges considered reliable by the community, or even better, a list of criteria by which to determine this for myself.

Comment: related: [What would a new exchange need to be better than the rest?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/24149/5406)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Based on the articles I've found, the real issues seems to be how to exchange national currency to bitcoin anonymously. The exchanges I've tried so far require a lot of personally identifiable information.